# Calculate statistics

Tags: python, statistics

1

If I have a number of files like this:

[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LDhM.png)

Inside each folder is 3 more like this:

[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3JT7.png)

Now inside each of these folders is a .txt file that looks like this:

[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1D1V.png)

For each of the .txt files I need to get the value from the 6th column in the file which I have circled in red and I am only interested in the lines that contain cope1, cope2, cope3, cope4 and cope5 at the start (highlighted in blue). Everything else can be ignored.

**PROBLEM**: I also need to write a script which can perform the following tasks:

- Work out how many participants you have
- Read in the relevant data from each of the files and store this in a
  sensible data structure
- Calculate the mean and standard deviation across subjects for each ROI and
  stimulus class (you will therefore end up with fifteen means and standard
  deviation)
- Print out the mean, standard deviation and number of samples which were used
  to calculate these to the screen as if it were a CSV file (with a header).

example of output:
[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBmAo.png)

I managed to complete until the mean part but now I am not sure how to include the standard deviation and the number of samples.

this is the output I have so far:

```
{'ffa': {'cope1': 0.6525,
         'cope2': 0.4146,
         'cope3': 0.5896,
         'cope4': 0.1521,
         'cope5': 0.5317},
 'lingual': {'cope1': -0.08865060000000001,
             'cope2': -0.150985,
             'cope3': -0.162005,
             'cope4': -0.130845,
             'cope5': -0.126411},
 'ppa': {'cope1': 0.74836,
         'cope2': 0.9444,
         'cope3': 0.300482,
         'cope4': 1.12435,
         'cope5': 0.8332200000000001}}
```

and now i need to add next to the mean the st. deviation and number of samples

I also need to convert each cope type to it's correspondent

```
cope1:  Bottle:
cope2: Chair:
cope3: Face: 
cope4: House: 
cope5: Shoe:
```

this is all the coding I have so far

```
import os
import csv
import pprint
import statistics

def main():
    values = {}
    ffaResults = {}
    lingualResults = {}
    ppaResults = {}

    dir = os.path.join("pin-assessment1-master", "roi_data")
    subdirs = os.listdir(dir)
    for subdir in subdirs:
        subdirpath = os.path.join(dir, subdir)
        subsubdirs = os.listdir(subdirpath)
        for subsubdir in subsubdirs:

            if subsubdir == "ffa":
                dirpath = os.path.join(subdirpath, subsubdir)
                files = os.listdir(dirpath)
                for filename in files:
                    path = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
                    with open(path, "r") as f:
                        content = csv.reader(f, delimiter=" ")
                        for row in content:
                            if "cope" in row[1]:
                                name = row[1].split("/")[1]
                                if not name in values:
                                    ffaResults[name] = [float(row[6])]
                                else:
                                    ffaResults[name].append(float(row[6]))  

            if subsubdir == "lingual_gyrus":
                dirpath = os.path.join(subdirpath, subsubdir)
                files = os.listdir(dirpath)
                for filename in files:
                    path = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
                    with open(path, "r") as f:
                        content = csv.reader(f, delimiter=" ")
                        for row in content:
                            if "cope" in row[1]:
                                name = row[1].split("/")[1]
                                if not name in lingualResults:
                                    lingualResults[name] = [float(row[6])]
                                else:
                                    lingualResults[name].append(float(row[6]))

            if subsubdir == "ppa":
                dirpath = os.path.join(subdirpath, subsubdir)
                files = os.listdir(dirpath)
                for filename in files:
                    path = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
                    with open(path, "r") as f:
                        content = csv.reader(f, delimiter=" ")
                        for row in content:
                            if "cope" in row[1]:
                                name = row[1].split("/")[1]
                                if not name in ppaResults:
                                    ppaResults[name] = [float(row[6])]
                                else:
                                    ppaResults[name].append(float(row[6]))
    res = {"ffa": {}, "lingual": {}, "ppa": {}}
    for k in ffaResults:
        res["ffa"][k] = statistics.mean(ffaResults[k]) 
    for k in lingualResults:
        res["lingual"][k] = statistics.mean(lingualResults[k]) 
    for k in ppaResults:
        res["ppa"][k] = statistics.mean(ppaResults[k]) 

    pprint.pprint(res)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use this code:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

li = []

# Traverses thru the root folder 'roi_data' tree and opens .txt files.
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('roi_data'):
    for name in files:
        # Opens .txt file as dataFrame and uses the second and the sixth columns.
        file_path = os.path.join(root, name)
        df = pd.read_csv(file_path, sep=' ', usecols=[1, 5], names=['cope', 'value'])
        
        # Filters out rows except those which contains 'cope'.
        # Adds ROI columns based on the file dir.
        df = df[df.iloc[:, 0].str.contains('cope')]
        df['roi'] = root.split("/")[-1]
        
        # Converts the column with the values into float.
        # Groups data by roi, cope and finds mean, std, count.
        df['value'] = df['value'].astype(float)
        
        # Adds files path to distinguish for which file the calculation is done.
        # Appends the dataframe to the list.
        df['file_path'] = file_path
        li.append(df)

# Concatenates all extracted dataframes.
combined_df = pd.concat(li)      

# Replaces values based on the dictionary.
di = {
    'stats/cope1': 'Bottle',
    'stats/cope2': 'Chair',
    'stats/cope3': 'Face',
    'stats/cope4': 'House',
    'stats/cope5': 'Shoe'
}
combined_df.replace(di, inplace=True)

# Aggregates the combined data and calculates the 'mean', 'std', 'count'.
# Saves the results into 'result.csv' and prints out the results.
result_df = combined_df.groupby(by=['roi', 'cope']).agg(['mean', 'std', 'count'])
result_df.to_csv('result.csv', sep='|')
print(result_df.to_string())
```

Output:

| roi | cope | mean | std | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ffa | Bottle | 0.76427 | 0.36723498396046694 | 10 |
| ffa | Chair | 0.7036800000000001 | 0.40113803609231574 | 10 |
| ffa | Face | 1.0842100000000001 | 0.39293685511938314 | 10 |
| ffa | House | 0.511365 | 0.394306610851392 | 10 |
| ffa | Shoe | 0.92214 | 0.48974865707943616 | 10 |
| lingual_gyrus | Bottle | -0.004992799999999994 | 0.26929961480881803 | 10 |
| lingual_gyrus | Chair | 0.0005299999999999909 | 0.35327198121434866 | 10 |
| lingual_gyrus | Face | -0.004019999999999993 | 0.3000928154569664 | 10 |
| lingual_gyrus | House | 0.018081 | 0.3216293944709932 | 10 |
| lingual_gyrus | Shoe | -0.002994999999999997 | 0.23756639419328654 | 10 |
| ppa | Bottle | 0.7706500000000001 | 0.49211155521667826 | 10 |
| ppa | Chair | 0.9696400000000001 | 0.44630525229065166 | 10 |
| ppa | Face | 0.327822 | 0.29263178903036335 | 10 |
| ppa | House | 1.14463 | 0.43584880673615856 | 10 |
| ppa | Shoe | 0.8539999999999999 | 0.5421760148799568 | 10 |

### Numpy implementation:

```
import os
import numpy as np

li = []

# Traverses thru the root folder 'roi_data' tree and opens .txt files.
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('roi_data'):
    for name in files:
        # Opens .txt file as numpy array and uses the second and the sixth columns.
        file_path = os.path.join(root, name)
        arr = np.loadtxt(file_path, delimiter=' ', usecols=[1, 5], dtype=str)
        
        # Filters out rows except those which contains 'cope'.
        # Adds ROI columns based on the file dir.
        arr = arr[np.char.startswith(arr[:, 0], 'stats/cope')]
        roi = np.full(fill_value=root.split("/")[-1], shape=(5, 1))
        arr = np.concatenate((roi, arr), axis=1)
        
        # Adds files path to distinguish for which file the calculation is done.
        # Appends the array to the list.
        file_path = np.full(fill_value=file_path, shape=(5, 1))
        arr = np.concatenate((arr, file_path), axis=1)
        li.append(arr)

# Concatenates all extracted arrays.
# Calculates the requested metrics and builds the result_di
combined_arr = np.array(li).reshape((-1, 4))
groups = (np.char.array(combined_arr[:, 0])
          + '_' + np.char.array(combined_arr[:, 1])).reshape((-1, 1))
combined_arr = np.concatenate((groups, combined_arr), axis=1)
result_di = dict()
for group in set(combined_arr[:, 0]):
    group_slice = combined_arr[combined_arr[:, 0] == group]
    values = (group_slice[:, 3].astype(float).mean(), 
              group_slice[:, 3].astype(np.float64).std(ddof=1),
              group_slice[:, 3].astype(np.float64).shape[0])
    result_di[group] = values

result_di =  dict(sorted(result_di.items()))
result_di

{'ffa_stats/cope1': (0.76427, 0.36723498396046694, 10),
 'ffa_stats/cope2': (0.7036800000000001, 0.4011380360923157, 10),
 'ffa_stats/cope3': (1.0842100000000001, 0.39293685511938314, 10),
 'ffa_stats/cope4': (0.511365, 0.394306610851392, 10),
 'ffa_stats/cope5': (0.92214, 0.4897486570794361, 10),
 'lingual_gyrus_stats/cope1': (-0.004992799999999996, 0.26929961480881803, 10),
 'lingual_gyrus_stats/cope2': (0.0005299999999999909, 0.35327198121434866, 10),
 'lingual_gyrus_stats/cope3': (-0.004019999999999996, 0.3000928154569664, 10),
 'lingual_gyrus_stats/cope4': (0.018081000000000003, 0.3216293944709932, 10),
 'lingual_gyrus_stats/cope5': (-0.0029950000000000024,
  0.23756639419328654,
  10),
 'ppa_stats/cope1': (0.77065, 0.49211155521667826, 10),
 'ppa_stats/cope2': (0.9696400000000001, 0.44630525229065166, 10),
 'ppa_stats/cope3': (0.32782199999999995, 0.2926317890303634, 10),
 'ppa_stats/cope4': (1.1446299999999998, 0.43584880673615867, 10),
 'ppa_stats/cope5': (0.8539999999999999, 0.5421760148799568, 10)}
```

Comment: I understand this is a really big problem and I tried to ask for help in small steps but then I asked to explain more and elaborate on the problem to understand what was the goal of what I was doing but thank you so much for your answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help again. You should be able to access the zip file through this link https://wetransfer.com/downloads/8a0041e81dbcc13a851908c9062df4cd20221223232125/f18a27

Comment: @Sophia I have updated the post. As I understood, the first you needed to combine the files and then aggregate them based on the 'roi' and 'cope' calculating mean, std, count. I have added the comments to the code so you can follow along. Couple of concepts you might find important to learn: 1. Walk thru the file tree efficiently, because your solution would fail to scale if there were more subfolders. 2. Pandas is your  number 1 friend for tabular data manipulation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer your comments are super useful! using pandas does seem a lot more easy but I haven't learnt it yet so I'm not allowed to use it to complete this...

Comment: could I use numpy instead of pandas since I can't use pandas yet? Thank you

Comment: I have added the numpy implementation, you owe me.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your code is clear and exactly what I needed. I hate to keep creating more problems but when I run the code in spider it said that 'combined_arr' was not defined. I'm so sorry to keep annoying you.

Comment: I have updated it, try again.

Comment: it all works now! Thank you again. Just one last question, in the end, do I print result_di? without printing it nothing appeared in the output but when I printed it the output was very strange like this and the numbers didn't match:  ({'roi_data\\01\\ffa_stats/cope1': (0.2577, nan, 1), 'roi_data\\01\\ffa_stats/cope2': (0.2311, nan, 1), 'roi_data\\01\\ffa_stats/cope3': (0.6393, nan, 1), 'roi_data\\01\\ffa_stats/cope4': (0.159, nan, 1), 'roi_data\\01\\ffa_stats/cope5': (0.6135, nan, 1), 'roi_data\\01\\lingual_gyrus_stats/cope1': (0.02977, nan, 1),  ...)

Comment: You got count 1, it means you did calculations for 1 folder only. You should have had 10. That is why std is nan.

Comment: but why is that happening? I have the same code as the one that you sent